# clearing selection is not working in select2

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I have implemented select2 widget, version 4. It works, but the x icon. It is not clearing the selection.

If you see this doc: https://select2.github.io/options.html, it says that this a problem in fact, but the documentation is incomplete for this.

Anyone has solved this already?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 15):

No it's not a bug. The "X" icon requires placeholder option.
Without it, clearAllow option cannot be used. So, right code will be like this:

```
$(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
    placeholder: "Put some text...",
    allowClear : true
});
```

By the way, there is undocumented option called *debug*. If you pass it to *select2()* method, the found errors will be printed on console. For example code in below:

```
  $(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
    //placeholder: "Put some text...",
    allowClear : true,
    debug: true
  });
```

Will get in browser's console:

[image: allowCreate requires placeholder option]

**Why allowClear requires placeholder option?**

The real drop down list, that you create with `<select>` and `<option>` elements hides by *select2*. And created new one.

In the new created drop down list, the field that user see (without drop down list) created automatically. Each time when you select new option, *select2* will change previous Field with new one.

When X icon clicked, it also delete main field. And creates new field with parameters of placeholder.

Comment: They should write this in the documentation with BIG BOLD letters first line!

Answer (score 8):

Finally I have found it is a bug in Select2 4.0.2.

The solution is this, in select2.js, line 1760.

This has to be replaced:

```
this.$element.val(this.placeholder.id).trigger('change');

this.trigger('toggle', {});
```

By:

```
 this.$element.val(this.placeholder.id).text(this.placeholder.text).trigger('change');

//this.trigger('toggle', {});
```

This solution also causes the dropdown not to appear when selection is cleared.

Comment: Dude. you rock! This was the issue for me and the additional fix about not showing the dropdown when its cleared also saved me from that. Kudos

Comment: Dude, you rock!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the clear button is not working even placeholder option is set. I need to add z-index property:

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
   z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding of the empty select option with value '' helped me.

Select2 4.0.3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes close button is not working due to long text. Use this css code.

```
 <style>
    .select2-selection__clear {
        position: absolute !important;
        right: 20px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: worked for me without !important